# Hiding/Showing Table Rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple table. When the document loads, all the table rows should be hidden. If a button is clicked, table rows related to that button should be displayed.

I have tried many solutions from StackOverflow, but nothing seems to work. When the button is clicked, the table does nothing at all. Thanks for helping me - it means a lot.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/td5npLuu/

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr class="all" class="row1">
                <td>R1C1</td>
                <td>R1C2</td>
                <td>R1C3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="all" class="row2">
                <td>R2C1</td>
                <td>R2C2</td>
                <td>R2C3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="all" class="row3">
                <td>R3C1</td>
                <td>R3C2</td>
                <td>R3C3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button id="showRow1">Show Row 1</button>
        <button id="showRow2">Show Row 2</button>
        <button id="showRow3">Show Row 3</button>
        <button id="showAllRows">Show All Rows</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function)
{
    $(".all").hide();

    $("#showRow1").click(function()
    {
        $(".row1").show();
        $(".row2").hide();
        $(".row3").hide();
    });

    $("#showRow2").click(function()
    {
        $(".row2").show();
        $(".row1").hide();
        $(".row3").hide();
    });

    $("#showRow3").click(function()
    {
        $(".row3").show();
        $(".row1").hide();
        $(".row2").hide();
    });

    $("#showAllRows").click(function()
    {
        $(".row1").show();
        $(".row2").show();
        $(".row3").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/wfgxadqg/1/)

1. Syntax error on this line, your are putting the word `function` inside paranthesis:

   `$(document).ready(function(){
       //
   });`
2. Change `class="all" class="row1"` to `class="all row1"`

Comment: Thank you for the response and Fiddle!

Comment: @Hus Actually, this answer doesn't solve your biggest problem - your code is inflexible and long - [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29334071) implementing your idea more professionally :)

Comment: Well, he just wanted to solve his problem. He did not wanted to make the code shorter and my answer was't meant to make flexible, just solve what problem he had.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes should only be used once per element. Instead of this:

```
<tr class="all" class="row1">
```

Use this:

```
<tr class="all row1">
```

When an attribute is used more than once, on an element, the last one will be used. This means that none of your elements have the `all` class.

Also, your Javascript is invalid:

```
$(document).ready(function)
{
    ...
});
```

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
});
```

This is how I would do it:

```
<table class="my-table">
    <tr class="row1"><td>R1C1</td><td>R1C2</td><td>R1C3</td></tr>
    <tr class="row2"><td>R2C1</td><td>R2C2</td><td>R2C3</td></tr>
    <tr class="row3"><td>R3C1</td><td>R3C2</td><td>R3C3</td></tr>
</table>
<button class="show-btn" data-show-row=".row1">Show Row 1</button>
<button class="show-btn" data-show-row=".row2">Show Row 2</button>
<button class="show-btn" data-show-row=".row3">Show Row 3</button>
<button class="show-btn" data-show-row=".row1,.row2,.row3">Show All Rows</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rows = $(".my-table tr").hide();
    $(".show-btn").on("click", function () {
        var showRow = $(this).data("show-row");
        rows.hide().filter(showRow).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That worked! You and Prashant have the same answer, but his has a Fiddle :P Sorry, mate. Thank you very much for helping me, though :)

Comment: Ugh, that's of course flexible, but  far too complicated... There is even no need to change html...

Comment: @nicael Could you please elaborate? I think it is rather elegant, if I may say so myself. If you needed to add more rows/buttons then it would just be a matter of adding them; no need to touch the Javascript.

Comment: I mean by making your script a short this way, you complicate the initial HTML -  without a real need to do it.

Comment: @nicael How is adding one attribute complicated? Also, if you can simplify your Javascript by moving something to the HTML then it is usually a good idea to do so (especially on larger projects). Complicated Javascript is much worse than complicated HTML.

Comment: The more your HTML repeats, the more you'll be affected by increasing the content of your repeating components. While the script doesn't repeat, so adding two-three lines to them instead of increasing HTML is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sverri already pointed, using `class="all" class="row1"` is invalid. Should be `class="all row1"`.

Apart from that:`$(document).ready()` is typoed:

```
$(document).ready(function()...
                         ^^^
```

And I would personally refactor all your huge and not flexible code to this flexible one:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".all").hide();
    });
    $("[id^='showRow']").click(function () {
        $(".all").hide();
        $(".row" + $(this).attr("id").replace("showRow", "")).show();
    });
    $("#showAllRows").click(function() {
        $(".all").show();   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="all row1">
        <td>R1C1</td>
        <td>R1C2</td>
        <td>R1C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="all row2">
        <td>R2C1</td>
        <td>R2C2</td>
        <td>R2C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="all row3">
        <td>R3C1</td>
        <td>R3C2</td>
        <td>R3C3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="showRow1">Show Row 1</button>
<button id="showRow2">Show Row 2</button>
<button id="showRow3">Show Row 3</button>
<button id="showAllRows">Show All Rows</button>
```